# How can i update a table by TransactionID? And can transactionId be the same when we update the data?

Tags: smart-contract, eosio-code

I am running my nodeos on my local machine, I can retrieve all the data via api and do some CRUD also. I have succeeded update the table by tableId,

But can someone suggest to me how do I update the table by transactionID? and can transactionId be the same when we update the data?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. You want to create a table that stores a transaction ID as the primary key and then modify that later?

Comment: @PhillipHamnett-EOS42 Hi, sorry for the late response, yes something like that. Do you have any idea? Because Eos primary key only allows uint64_t and uint128_t.